# Assembly Language: Write a general-purpose program that correct an extra character in a string

Tags: assembly, masm

I am trying to solve the following problem using Assembly Language with MASM:

```
Write a general-purpose program that correct an extra character in a string. For example, in “Excellent time too listen to music” program should remove the extra o. Here is a sample call:

.data

str1 BYTE “Excellent time too listen to music”,0

.code
```

I have the following code:

```
.386
.model flat,stdcall
.stack 4096
ExitProcess proto,dwExitCode:dword
.data
str1 BYTE “Excellent time too listen to music”
.code
main proc
    mov al, char
    mov edi, offset str1
    mov ecx, length str1 
    cld 
    repne scasd            ; scan for the character 
    jnz end                ; if if no 'o'
    cmp [edi], al          ; check if next charater is 'o'
    jmpnz end 
    ; remainder of ecx
    mov esi, edi 
    mov edi, edi -1 
    rep movsd
main endp
end main
```

When I compile it on Visual Studio, I got the following errors:

[image]

**Update:**
I updated the quotation mark on line 6 and remove errors for line 6, 10, and 11.
Here is the update script and error log.

```
.386
.model flat,stdcall
.stack 4096
ExitProcess proto,dwExitCode:dword
.data
str1 BYTE "Excellent time too listen to music" 
.code
main proc
    mov al, char
    mov edi, offset str1
    mov ecx, length str1 
    cld 
    repne scasd            ; scan for the character 
    jnz end                ; if if no 'o'
    cmp [edi], al          ; check if next charater is 'o'
    jmpnz end 
    ; remainder of ecx
    mov esi, edi 
    mov edi, edi -1 
    rep movsd
main endp
end main
```

[image]

Comment: Those quotes around the string do not appear to be normal quotes.

Comment: How should I handle those quotes?

Comment: Delete them and retype.

Comment: Thanks, that removed the errors for line 6, 10, and 11.

Comment: Okay, next up is `mov al, char` - assembler is right, there's nothing named `char` in your code. What was your intention here?

Comment: you probably want `char equ '0'`.  (If `char` isn't a reserved keyword in masm).  Also, `scasd` checks a whole dword at once; you want `scasb` for this.

Comment: Do you mean change the content from `mov al, char` to `mov al, 0`?